# Problem installing ATI driver 13.3 beta on Ubuntu Precise 12.04

Tags: 12.04, drivers, ati

OS: Ubuntu Precise 12.04 LTS 64 bit
Kernel : 3.5.0-27-generic
Header files:

> dpkg -s linux-headers-$(uname -r) 
> Package:
>   linux-headers-3.5.0-27-generic 
> Status: install ok installed

deb packages build successfully via :

> sudo sh amd-driver-installer-catalyst-13.3-beta3-linux-x86.x86_64.run
>   --buildpkg Ubuntu/precise

But when I try to install sudo apt-get install fglrx*.deb I see it is unable to find linux header files.

> dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of fglrx:  fglrx
>   depends on linux-headers-generic | linux-headers; however:   Package
>   linux-headers-generic is not installed.   Package linux-headers is not
>   installed.

It seems it is looking for 3.2.x kernel header files which are default for 12.04

How to resolve this issue?

Comment: I recommend reading this link http://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/driver-to-use-when-installing-an-nvidia-ati-or-intel-video-card/61433#61433 . For more specific information read the answer provided by chaskes.

Comment: UPDATE: Something unpredictable happened. It installed by itself dont know how. now, if I remove xorg.conf (YES REMOVE) it shows me tear free desktop option and works flawlessly but using my integrate GPU instead of discrete. If I run amdconfig --initial it creates xorg.conf but i have tearing and no tear free option in cccle :/

Comment: Look at the Installation Guide carefully. You may need to follow the section to remove everything and start fresh. Also see the section on video tearing at the Installation Guide. If that doesn't work, look at the (linked from the guilde) workaround (a PPA) for AMD switchable graphics.

Comment: You mean PPA from second link or the wiki.cchtml link ?

Comment: @luis-alvarado Great answer on the the drivers question. I had just added it my answer when I saw your comment :)

Comment: The Guide links to a workaround for hybrid graphics at: (https://help.ubuntu.com/community/BinaryDriverHowto/ATI#WORKAROUND) . A lot depends on your actual hardware. I had to first use the workaround, then that broke for me after a kernel upgrade, and I then had to install the driver from the AMD website. The drivers in the repository never worked for me.

Comment: chaskes Is it possible if you can help step by step? I can remove the drivers and go back to open source, now for clean install what to do? simply install linux-headers-generic (installed already) and build deb files again?

Comment: I'm happy to help with additional questions, but we can't turn the comments into a chat (and I can't chat right now). My best advice: Using the Guide: 1) follow the instructions to remove fgrlx* and the pre-build instructions; 2) then try the instructions at the workaround.. 3) if that doesn't work, do the remove again, and follow the Guide on installing from Catalyst website. Remember that if things don't work right away you may get low-graphics mode and need to use `ctrl-alt-f1` to open a browser from the terminal and get to the instructions.

Answer (score 0):

You need to install the `linux-headers-generic` package, a meta-package that always points to the latest generic kernel header available. `fglrx` depends on this package.

```
sudo apt-get install linux-headers-generic
```

There are good instructions for building and installing the AMD drivers (albeit, written for Quantal) at [Ubuntu Quantal Installation Guide](http://wiki.cchtml.com/index.php/Ubuntu_Quantal_Installation_Guide#Removing_Catalyst.2Ffglrx). It gives the prerequisites as:

```
sudo apt-get install build-essential cdbs dh-make dkms execstack dh-modaliases linux-headers-generic fakeroot
```

Plus `sudo apt-get install lib32gcc1` when using 64-bit.

Note that the list includes `linux-headers-generic`, not the specific name of the latest generic headers package.

For additional detailed information on installing video drivers, see:

[Which driver should I install when using an Nvidia, Ati or Intel video card](https://askubuntu.com/questions/61396/which-driver-should-i-install-when-using-an-nvidia-ati-or-intel-video-card)

Comment: I am not using Quantal.
But thanks, I am using same website for Precise :)

Comment: That doesn't matter :). You still need to install `linux-headers-generic` to satisfy the dependency.

Comment: Please read my comments update above. :( it installed and behave strangely